# Process manager with Python

Tags: python, rest

The system I have in mind looks like a client-server app, with a simple REST API, where the clients can ask the server to start "worker processes" for a given task (POST), query their existence (GET) and stop them (DELETE).

The "worker process" (I don't know how to call it - that's why the question's title is so bad) runs in the background, in my case, this is a connection to an industrial control system, where a Python functions acts as a callback triggered by external events. Basically this is data acquisition.

So the `client` asks the server to start a process to do the data acquisition of something, until it asks the server to stop it.

Does that translates to a common problem that has a nice solution?

The question is not about the REST part, but on the part where the server manage services.

It does **not** seem to be solved using a asyn queue and a pool of workers...

Comment: You are talking more in terms of RPC with a restful api

Comment: Exactly! I found this a minute ago : http://supervisord.org/api.html . This looks like the solution.

Comment: supervisord is a good process manager, but AFAIK can only tell you about the running state of the process (stopped/started/restarting) - not more detail such as what domain specific task is it processing, what percentage of the task is complete etc.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Yes, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Also, I want to be able to run an arbitrary number of instances of a number of processes.